# 404 error when add application in "Default web site" in IIS (Version 10)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I add an application into IIS's (IIS version 10) 'Default Web Site' section but I am facing a problem. When I browse that application some error showing on console. Screenshots are given below :

[image]

[image: Errors]

I google a lot but can't find any solution for IIS version 10 in windows 10.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The root cause here is that you've added your web application as a virtual directory, and you're calling to a url/resource based on your root (localhost).  Please provide the relevant Login button (control) click handling code as well as relevant portions of your web.config, so that a more comprehensible answer can be given.  If you're using ASP webcontrols, please provide the aspx portion as well.

Comment: I have added my web as application, not virtual directory.  I want browse my application using localhost/hrmis. It redirect my application perfectly, but when i want to login, its showing 404 error. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I misspoke, I shouldn't have used the term virtual directory to describe what I meant there.   your login attempt is throwing a 404 because it's calling to uri at localhost/home and it doesn't resolve to anything (my presumption is that it should be localhost/hrmis/home/ or something like that).  the issue here is likely in your web application: a configuration one or implementation of a client-side script using root relative uri.. something like that.

Comment: as written, this question is **too broad** to answer; it is equivalent to asking why your web application calling to "localhost/home/ValidateUserLogin".

Answer (score 1):

Please try converting to application in IIS manager, I believe this would solve your issue

Comment: It was added as an application. no any option to convert, because it was not a virtual directory. In IIS previous version i was able to host & run application.